# Datepicker end date picker yearrange select from the start date year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
$('#stpartdates').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function(date) {
        var date2 = $('#stpartdates').datepicker('getDate');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 365);
        $('#etpartdates').datepicker('setDate', date2);
        $('#etpartdates').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
    }
});
$('#etpartdates').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: $('#stpartdates').val(),
    onSelect: function() {
        //  $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
    }
});
```

`stpartdates` is an startdate , `etpartdates` is an end date , 
if user select `04-08-2014` i want to display the year range for the end date is only `2015`

i mean

```
start date year + 1 = end date yearrange
```

Comment: Try my ultimate plugin for this - http://yaireo.github.io/dateRangePicker/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
    year = date.getFullYear() + 1;
$("#etpartdates").datepicker("option", "minDate", "01/01/" + year);
```

instead of

`$('#etpartdates').datepicker('setDate', date2);`

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4UAJ3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
    $("#stpartdates,#etpartdates").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText, obj) {
        var MinDate = new Date(dateText);
        var MaxDate = new Date(dateText);
        var newDateRangeMax = new Date(MinDate.getFullYear()+1,MinDate.getMonth(),MinDate.getDate());
        var newDateRangeMin = new Date(MaxDate.getFullYear()-1, MaxDate.getMonth(),MaxDate.getDate());
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "stpartdates") {
            $("#etpartdates").datepicker("option", "minDate", newDateRangeMin );
        }
        else{

            $("#stpartdates").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newDateRangeMax)

        }
    });
```